# Dropbox automatic synchronization?

Tags: dropbox

I downloaded Dropbox to back up my desktop PC when the fantastic Ubunu One closed.

Ubuntu One automatically uploaded all new files as well as changes to any existing files.

Im not too sure how dropbox works because When I add data to an existing file  on my PC it does not appear to be updated by dropbox.

Does dropbox upload all new files and changes to files automatically or do I have to remember to upload after creating a new file or changing an existing one.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Dropbox HP](https://www.dropbox.com/), [Dropbox Tour](https://www.dropbox.com/tour) and [Dropbox Help Center](https://www.dropbox.com/help) might be of use to you!

Dropbox automatically, when you put your new file into the Dropbox hierarchy uploads them, and also synchronizes them instantly, if you check/activate the following options in the preferences menu:

- Under `General` tab mark the `Enable LAN sync` option.
- Under `Account` tab - `Selective sync: Select which folders sync to this computer:` You need to mark all your folders, that should be synced!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tend to work with alot of Data sheets on Libre and all are synced through the dropbox folder and  mobile app. Its seems quite fine that I have just moved from Ubuntu One aswell.

If all the data that you have is updated in the Dropbox folder, Im positive things should be fine.

Did check box the automatic sync option within settings ?